# Select corresponding value from max value in a column for current week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, I have created the the table below:

**Current Week:
4/12/21 *(represented by: =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3))***

**Most availability for current week:
Person 1**

| Team Member | 4/12/21 | 4/19/21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | 10% | 25% |
| Person 2 | 5% | 50% |

**What I am trying to do:**

For the current week's column, automatically determine the max value and return the Team Member's name.

**What I used thus far:**

=INDEX(A8:A,MATCH(MAX(B8:B),B8:B,0))

This formula makes me manually select the column, I am hoping to have the column selected automatically based on the current week, which is why I have it represented above the table as it's own cell using the formula to identify the current week. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table header row is 7 then this formula may work:

`=INDEX(A8:A,MATCH(MAX(FILTER(B8:C,B7:C7=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3))),FILTER(B8:C,B7:C7=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)),0))`

Comment: Yes this works, thank you! So I can simply adjust wherever there is a "C" to the final column in my actual sheet? The weeks go across through to columns D,E,F,G...all the way to "AM"

Comment: Correct.  Actually I realised you don't need to specify column C in the row 7 criteria - just use B7:7 as the range